# How to Create a Stacked Column Chart with Dynamic Series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a Stacked Bar chart with the series being dynamic (unlike Highcharts example with hard coded series).  I have done the following but it does not create the stacked columns for the different series

```
    Highcharts.chart(this.chartElement.nativeElement, {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: '',

      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: this.rptng_months
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: '',
        min: 0,
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },     
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'black',
            style: {
              textOutline: 0
            },
          }
        }
      },
      series: this.data.map(x=>x.Scheduled_Open),
    });
```

I've also tried the Series section like this:

```
series: [
{
  name: this.data.map(n=>n.Container),
  data:this.data.map(x=>x.Scheduled_Open),
  type: 'column',
  cursor: 'pointer'
},
```

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
| Container   |RPTNG_Months|Scheduled_Open|
|-------------|------------|--------------|
|Container 1  |  1/1/2021  |   140        |
|Container 1  |  2/1/2021  |   140        |
|Container 1  |  3/1/2021  |   140        |
|Container 1  |  4/1/2021  |   140        |
|Container 2  |  1/1/2021  |   1117       |
|Container 2  |  2/1/2021  |   1119       |
|Container 2  |  3/1/2021  |   1119       |
|Container 2  |  4/1/2021  |   1119       |
|Container 3  |  1/1/2021  |   1359       |
|Container 3  |  2/1/2021  |   1359       |
|Container 3  |  3/1/2021  |   1358       |
|Container 3  |  4/1/2021  |   1357       |
|Container 4  |  1/1/2021  |   1237       |
|Container 4  |  2/1/2021  |   1237       |
|Container 4  |  3/1/2021  |   1238       |
|Container 4  |  4/1/2021  |   1238       |
```

In the dataset above there are 4 different containers. However there could be any number of containers. Note that I sanitized the names for this example. The names are actually meaningful.

How can I create a stacked column with dynamic series using Highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the series data dynamically can be achieved by loading it in the load event and performing a series update using the update method.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
            series = [{
                name: 'London',
                data: [78.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
              }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
              }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [45.4, 45.2, 44.5, 121.7, 52.6, 44.5, 35.4, 55.4, 77.6, 65.1, 64.8, 33.1]
              }, {
                name: 'Las Vegas',
                data: [23.4, 23.2, 23.5, 23.7, 23.6, 32.5, 32.4, 32.4, 32.6, 39.1, 32.8, 23.1]
              }
            ];
          chart.update({
            series: series
          }, true, true);
      }
    }
  },
```

Use data.seriesMapping to customize your data. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping.